# TSQL Convert select statement to update with joins

Tags: select, join

I have the following select statement:

```
SELECT  projectid,documentid,revisionno,configurationid,variable45,
        ISNULL(Variable45, (SELECT TOP 1 variable45 FROM pivot_table WHERE documentid = t.documentid and projectid=t.projectid
        and configurationid=t.configurationid and cast(revisionno as int) < cast(t.revisionno as int) AND Variable45 is NOT NULL 
        ORDER BY projectid desc,documentid desc ,revisionno desc,configurationid desc)) as NewCol
FROM    pivot_table t;
```

I tried converting to an update stement the following way, but I get wrong records updates. Can anyone help me resolve my problem:

```
UPdate PIVOT_TABLE
set variable45 = ((SELECT TOP 1 variable45 FROM pivot_table t WHERE t.documentid = documentid and t.projectid=projectid
        and t.configurationid=configurationid and cast(t.revisionno as int) < cast(revisionno as int) AND Variable45 is NOT NULL 
        ORDER BY revisionno desc)) where Variable45 is NULL;
```

DB: SQLExpress2008.

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out:

```
    UPdate pt
    set pt.variable45 = ((SELECT TOP 1 t.variable45 FROM pivot_table t WHERE 
t.documentid = pt.documentid and t.projectid=pt.projectid and t.configurationid=pt.configurationid and cast(t.revisionno as int) < cast(pt.revisionno as int) AND t.variable45 is NOT NULL 
            ORDER BY revisionno desc)) from PIVOT_TABLE pt where pt.variable45 is NULL;
```